# Are'nt we Allowed to write html codes if we use backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am learning backbone.js and I have seen some examples like [this one](https://gist.github.com/nakhli/1596813).Here the user has not written much html codes inside the `editor.html`.Only 4 lines of code.But for colour change,size change etc he has done inside `editor.js`

Please help me understand what all codes we need to keep inside `.html` file

```
<div id="page" style="width:2000px;height:2000px;">
    <button id="new-rectangle">New Rectangle</button>
    <button id="new-circle">New Circle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter I know you are talented person,But As I said I am a learner,If you can not help me and can not encourage then please do not discourage me also

Comment: I believe the reason for the downvote (it wasn't me) is that you don't have a specific problem along the lines of "this is broken, here is what I've tried to do to fix it. What am I doing wrong". StackOverflow is geared to answer these kind of questions, not genral "best practices" questions. As it stands your question is very broad.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for sharing information,I have seen many questions like where can I download backbone js,how to start etc.So I thought we can also ask this type of questions.And also for beginners in the future may get benefitted

Answer (score 1):

You should aim to put all your html in .html file(s). As an app grows, it will help you to keep them separate. The example you link to is a 'simplified' version - this is not how you would structure things in an actual app. You would load html from templates in the render function. A (though this is also simplified as I am relying on script tags) pattern would be:

HTML file:

```
[...SOME HTML...]
<script type="text/html" id="template-contact">
  <div class='contact'>
    <h1>Here's my template code</h1>
    <strong>name</strong>
    <span>email</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Then in your Backbone view render function:

```
 render: function() {

   template: _template($('#template-contract').html(),

    this.$el.html(this.template()); 
    return this;
 }
```

Then somewhere else in your Backbone code you create a new instance of the view and render it.

```
var example = new view_name();

example.render(); //This loads the html template
```

If you need to dynamically load the html from a server, you can use underscore (or whichever template engine you are using) tags in your template '<%>' and use models. This is best explained in Addy Osmani's book *Developing Backbone.js Applications* which, incredibly, is free. Here's [the link to the relevant section](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#templates)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750110/how-to-collect-all-the-images-from-a-folder) though I accepted the answer but I didnt find it useful.Can you post your answer and also can tell me if the fiddle is as per backbone MVC?

Comment: Can I expect a reply from you?

Comment: Glad you found it useful -  I've got to take care of something else now, so can't look at the other question. Might be able to check it out tomorrow.

Comment: ohh yes,But please have a look and answer if possible.Thanks again.I will upvote your answer also

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you wants to display on the browser you can keep it in `.html` file and logic to update the dom on run time should be in `.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I hope you are not the downvoter.If I want to show different images then where will I keep.For example there are 3 buttons.If click 1st button then show the 1st image and click on the 2nd button then show the 2nd image

Comment: Put image tags in html file with 1st visible and other two hidden(display:none), now logic goes in js for clicking the button change visibility accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again.If the images are dynamic,then where will I keep the images.

Comment: If images are dynamic then whole logic will go in js.
No need to be thanks, if answer is useful then mark it as answer. I can't help you in down-vote of your post.