# How to collect all the images from a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/20/)

when you click on next then new images are loaded.But the new images are loaded from internet.

In my app all the images are located in **img/image** folder and the image names are **1.jpg,hi.png** etc

So how can I show the images when I click on next

I thought i will modify `var srcs = [ 'http://lorempixel.com/150/100/city', 'http://lorempixel.com/150/100/sports' ];` with `var srcs = [ 'img/image/1.jpg', 'img/image/hi.png' ];`

But if I do this way then the problem will be I have to change `var srcs` if I add a new image to the folder

For example If after a later time I add **3.jpg** then I have to manually `var srcs = [ 'img/image/1.jpg', 'img/image/hi.png','img/image/3.jpg' ];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to load all images in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144261/javascript-how-to-load-all-images-in-a-folder)

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE Thanks for sharing information.I have seen that link before asking but it was not working for me.I mean the 2nd answer and yes all my image names are sequential

Comment: So when you say `1.jpg,hi.png` do you mean `1.jpg,2.png` ?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE yes,I have changed the image names 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg etc

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE Can I have your answer?

Comment: I'm trying to set up a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example that can help you, it's not optimal but works http://jsfiddle.net/PrVRq/ :

```
$('.images').on('loaded', function () {// load an image}
```

try to load the next image

```
img.load(function () {    
    $('.images').append(img);
    $('.images').trigger('loaded');
});
```

if the image is loaded trigger the loaded event to load another one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Actually my requirement is when I click on next then new 2 images will appear and the old 2 images will disappear

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I am new to backbone and so if you dont mind can I ask your email id?

Comment: If you have any question about Backbone, just ask it in SO and I or someone else will help you for sure ;)

Comment: I am a beginner is javascript and backbone.I will not ask you write codes but I need some ideas how to do.And you know SO is not the right place to ask for ideas.If I post question asking for ideas then my post will be closed as off the topic.Unless I have codes,I can not post in SO.Thanks